# Does PyFilesystem's s3 filesystem support python 3?

Tags: python, pyfilesystem

The documentation for PyFilesystem's s3fs (S3 filesystem) says that it is only supported in python 2 because boto only supports python 2.

https://pyfilesystem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/s3fs.html

However Boto3 is released and stable:

https://github.com/boto/boto3

I just wanted to verify that the documentation is still accurate on this point. I'm unable to import `fs.s3fs` in my python 3 environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 filesystem does support boto3, there's an old version of the docs lurking around that can throw you off. Also a separate pip install is necessary for this filesystem.

Documented in a separate repo here:

https://github.com/PyFilesystem/s3fs

```
pip install fs-s3fs
```

```
from fs_s3fs import S3FS
s3fs = S3FS('mybucket')
```